# How do I keep \n in my string

Tags: javascript, replace

I need to remove all invalid xml chars from my string, but I still need the carriage return

```html
function CleanInvalidXmlChars(s) {
     s = s.replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '')
     return s;
 }
```

Comment: which language?

Comment: The language is Javascript

Comment: You don't need to escape all these characters, only `-` and `/`

Comment: just add \n in your exclusion list : [^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~\n]*